# Cheap Internet access in Cuba for tourists?

Tags: budget, tips-and-tricks, internet, cuba

We just arrived in Havana, and have discovered that Internet is a bit of a rarity here.  Most large hotels offer Internet for CUC6-10 per hour.  The only mobile Internet I have found is from [ETESCA](http://www.etecsa.cu/?page=telefonia_movil&sub=cubacel_pmf) and runs 1CUC per 1mb and is only for email.

Is there a more affordable way to access the Internet while traveling in Cuba?

I'm on vacation right now, but my normal mode of travel is as a digital nomad. How do digital nomads survive in the digital desert that is Cuba?  Are there any tips and tricks for getting inexpensive Internet here?

Comment: What little Internet there is in Cuba is heavily controlled by the state, so it's not likely (unless you want to [wind up in prison for subversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Gross) or something).

Comment: You have to know some Cubans, there you can find other options for 2 dollars/hour in some houses..Tienes que caminar como se dice en Cuba. @Flimzy I was in Cuba from 22 march-3 april en la Habana Vieja

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't exist. Per [Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Havana)

> Internet cafes can be found at ETESCA (the state telephone company) offices, in Hotel Habana Libre, Hotel Inglatera (cheapest but slowest), Hotel Nacional and at the Capitolio.

The Wikipedia article on [ETECSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ETECSA):

> The cost of Internet access is CUC$4.50 per hour (or CUC$0.60 for domestic intranet access and CUC$1.50 for email),

Still Wikipedia on [Internet in Cuba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_in_Cuba)

> The average cost of a one-hour cybercafé connection is about $1.50 U.S. dollars for the national network and $5 to $7 U.S. dollars for the international network,

To be fair, the same article mentions a black market where

> the black market consists of professional or former government officials who have been cleared to have Internet access. These individuals sell or rent their usernames and passwords to citizens who want to have access

Obviously, there's no price and in a country like Cuba you quite probably don't want to deal with a black market.

Comment: In countries like Cuba, most of the time the only option is the black market.

Comment: That requires a bit of ... savviness would be a good word -- you really don't want to get caught.

Comment: I lived in cuba, It's sad to said, but most of the time the only way to get food was the black market. Now is a bit better, but yet almost everithing you need is not available in the official store just in the black market

Answer (score 0):

Right now the best service that I found is that
[digicelcubaroaming](https://www.digicelcubaroaming.com/Buy-A-Sim?locale=en)

Is the typical sim with roaming services, you can buy in US and also in Cuba on Revolico.com. This services support Android devices, I have never tested in iPhone but I think is pretty the same thing. I hope that help you

Comment: Welcome to the site! Are you somehow affiliated with this service?

Comment: Yes I'm Cuban and also live in the US and I bought a sim to communicate with my family.