# What is the daily fee for using a local SIM card in Cuba?

Tags: cellphones, internet, cuba

I've reading about SIM card in Cuba. [In some websites](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/americas-cuba/topics/sim-card-for-tourists/compact) talk about a tax of 3 CUC per day to have a Cuban SIM card. In other websites don't. What's the current situation? If I want to make local calls (1 or 2 per day) and access to Internet (2-4 hours per week), should I pay 3 CUC/day? If that's true, I assume that it will be cheaper to use a phone booth to call and an ETECSA wifi access point to navigate...

Comment: You won't get access to Internet on any Cuban SIM card. It's not an option (except for email). See [this post](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/45244/444).

Comment: Note also (I was there last month) ETECSA tends to be pc terminals only - no wifi.

Comment: @MarkMayo everything is changing very fast. Now there are wifi spots in almost every city, fast and reliable, but a bit expensive (2 CUC per hour).

Comment: @Ivan I was only there in July, with two other IT geeks, we regularly checked for wifi in Havana, Varadero and Trinidad (and asked) and apart from at the resorts, nobody knew of any...so while they may well exist, they're not easy to find yet :/

Comment: @MarkMayo I've been there in August. In fact, 72 hours ago I was at Havana :) In all international hotels and many city places like "La rampa", "El Capitolio", etc there are public wifi spots. This is why I say that "everything is changing very fast" ;)

Comment: @Ivan wow, yeah, very fast!!

Comment: @MarkMayo The wifi hotspots [were announced mid-june](http://laredcubana.blogspot.ca/2015/06/cubas-wifi-access-plan-raises.html) and [opened during the first week of august](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/the_americas/havanas-hottest-spot-is-a-crowded-ramp-to-wifi-bliss/2015/08/07/d1e2570c-3bb6-11e5-88d3-e62130acc975_story.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(...)talk about a tax of 3 CUC per day(...)
```

Actually it's not a tax, it's a regular service fee.

The information you are requesting can be found on the company website (in Spanish):

[Etecsa - Mobile Phone Services- Contract and Activation](http://www.etecsa.cu/?page=telefonia_movil&sub=contratacion_y_activacion)

- The service charge is 3 CUC (+- 3 USD) per day
- The minimal duration of a contract is 3 days
- You need to pay all the daily fees in advance for the period you will be using the line.
- Phone calls are paid independently
- You also need to add funds to your account for a minimum of 10 CUC (+- 10 USD)
- No internet service (there is data roaming if you bring a phone from another country, but this is **VERY** expensive)

Additionally, there are wifi hotspots in most hotels and [at a few public places in all major cities around the country](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/the_americas/havanas-hottest-spot-is-a-crowded-ramp-to-wifi-bliss/2015/08/07/d1e2570c-3bb6-11e5-88d3-e62130acc975_story.html), there is an access fee of 2 CUC per hour that should be paid in advance.