# How to use payphone for calls within Cuba?

Tags: cuba, phone-networks, havana

I am considering to use payphone to contact *casa particular* administrators when I will be in Cuba. Should I buy some kind of card for it? How much does it cost? How to call? Are there any other cheap options to make calls within Cuba?

Comment: Somehow relevant: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51142/what-is-the-daily-fee-for-using-a-local-sim-card-in-cuba/55733#55733

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are public phones in Cuba, and they look like this

[image]

In order to call you need phone card (*tarjeta propia*) sold at [ETECSA stores](http://bestcubaguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/ETECSA-Facturas.jpg), it has blue color. Phone cards are sold in CUCs ($5, $10, and $20) and in Cuban national currency (3, 5, and 7 pesos).
Addresses of ETECSA stores are listed [here.](http://www.etecsa.cu/contacto/red_comercial/)

**UPDATE**: there are three types of phones in Cuba though:

- the ones that accept only CUC cards, they have card slot in the top and allow both international and domestic calls
- the ones that accept only CUP cards, they allow only domestic calls
- the ones that accept only local coins (*nacional moneda*), they are intended mainly for locals.

Another, more expensive way, is making call from hotel landline, either from room or lobby.

But, all in all, I recommend you to apply some international roaming plan just in your home country and that's it. It would be much simpler and cheaper in majority of cases (it depends).

Comment: What's the difference between CUC and CUP card?

Comment: @Justas, cards sold in CUC can be used both for domestic and overseas calls, whilst CUP cards are not. As you are gonna make call within Cuba, you can use either of them. See the update.

Comment: The CUC phones have blue color, as on the picture.

Comment: The are no color distinctions for CUP vs CUP phones... you can find them both in blue, black, dark-blue, grey etc